# How can I connect Ubuntu 22.04 server to a Mobile USB tethering? The server is offline now

Tags: server, internet, connection

I have installed Ubuntu server 22.04 with the default configurations. I wanted to use my mobile network through USB Tethering but the server is not using the network. How can i connect the server to the Internet through my mobile network. The server does not have a wireless card that is my problem, and i do not have a network cable with internet access?
Since i'm not connected to the internet, i could not install network tool and other tools.

Comment: No I did not, I could not connect the server to the internet. Is there a way to install it offline?

Comment: [Improve your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422924/edit) rather than putting answers in comments. Comments can be deleted. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable (not for conversation).